# Looking for Wss 3.0 vhd

Tags: wss-3.0

i am looking for PRE-Configured VHD for WSS 3.0 please. I have been looking on google but not able to find any, so if anyone knows please let me know here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MOSS 2007 you can get a pre-configured VM with trial version OS, Office etc. here
http://www.pilothouseconsulting.com/forms/all/virtualpc2007.html

You don't have to buy their training DVDs to get the VM but you have to fill out a short form and they'll send you an email with the download link and credentials.

Answer (score 1):

The chances of you finding one that is legitimate is next to 0 as WSS 3.0 is two version in the past and has passed out of [mainstream support as of October 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=sharepoint%20services&Filter=FilterNO&wa=wsignin1.0). You are probably going to have to build your own.